# Inverse function and cardinalities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

We'll define a function between two sets A and B:

$H: ((A \cup B )\to ${0,1} ) $\to ((A \to ${0,1}) $\times (B \to ${0,1}))

$H= \lambda f \in (A \cup B ) \to ${0,1}$.<\lambda a \in A . f(a),\lambda b \in B.f(b)>$

1. If H is invertible, what is the cardinality of $A \cap B$?
2. Present the inverse function of H.

**What I did:**
I figured that from the fact that H is invertible I can figure $2^{|A \cup B|}=2^{|A|} \cdot 2^{|B|}= 2^{|A \times B|}$
I also know that$ |A \cap B| $= |A| +|B| -$|A \cup B |$ but from there I don't really have a clue how to proceed..

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: $2^{|A|}\cdot 2^{|B|} = 2^{|A|+|B|}$.

Comment: A more intuitive approach is as follows: if $H$ is invertible and the arguments of $H^{-1}$ are $f_A$ and $f_B$, then for $f$ to exists we need $f_A$ and $f_B$ to agree at $A \cap B$, that is $\forall x \in A \cap B.\ f_A(x) = f_B(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Note that $H$ is always injective (one-to-one); the question is whether it’s surjective (onto). Suppose that $c\in A\cap B$. Define

$$f:A\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x=c\\0,&\text{if }x\ne c\end{cases}$$

and

$$g:B\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto 0\;;$$

is $\langle f,g\rangle$ in the range of $H$?

Comment: so from what I understand, because H is invertible (therefore surjective and injective) then |$A \cap B$| = 0 . That is because the function g you defined is not surjective (therefore not in the range of H)

Comment: @user1685224: It’s true that $g$ is not surjective, but that’s beside the point: the point is that $H$ is not surjective, so it’s not invertible. But yes, what I did can be done whenever $|A\cap B|>0$, so in order for $H$ to be surjective and hence invertible, we must have $|A\cap B|=0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So is it a sufficient proof just to say that : $2 ^ {|A \cup B|}$ = $2 ^{|A|} \cdot 2^{|B|} = 2^{|A| + |B|}$

so:
$|A| + |B| = |A \cup B|$

$|A \cup B| =|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$
so 

$|A \cap B| =0$ or should I use functions as examples like here?

Comment: @user1685224: Your calculation works when $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, but the result that $H$ is invertible if and only if $A\cap B=\varnothing$ is true in general, not for finite sets. The calculation doesn’t work if at least one of $A$ and $B$ is infinite, so for the general result you do need to use a different argument, and the one that I suggested is probably the simplest.

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot!

Comment: @user1685224: You’re welcome!